# Is it possible to impl database 'trigger' in java code? (hibernate + jpa + spring + mysql)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, triggers

I am using mysql 5.5 DB, hibernate.4.0 as jpa provider to spring 3.0.5.

I have a `user` table and `privilege` table in my DB. Also I have some triggers in my DB. Those trigger implements some of our application's business logic.

For example, user `john` insert a record into table `table_foo` via my web application.

1. The trigger `BeforeInsertTableFoo` will check the user's privilege. If user doesn't have the privilege, trigger will abort this operation.
2. Also, if the operation is permitted, another trigger `AfterInsertTableFoo` will update some records in Table `table_bar`.

Is there any way that I can implement this logic as 'trigger' in java code? It seems like Jpa Event Listener and Hibernate Event can only do something like trigger but only in one table.

Surely I can use a java class to do the same thing. But I can't make sure that all the other developer, even myself, will use the correct java class to do db insertion or update, when the amount of business rules increased.

Thx in advance.
andrew

Comment: hey, have you got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

Check the JPA's listener more carefully. You can make *one* listener for *many* entities / tables.

Just set a listener class like this:

```
public class MyListener {
@PrePersist void onPrePersist(Object entity ) {}
@PostPersist void onPostPersist(Object entity) {}
@PostLoad void onPostLoad(Object entity) {}
@PreUpdate void onPreUpdate(Object entity) {}
@PostUpdate void onPostUpdate(Object entity) {}
@PreRemove void onPreRemove(Object entity) {}
@PostRemove void onPostRemove(Object entity) {}
```

}

And then, for all the entities for which you want a call back or "trigger" ...

```
@Entity @EntityListeners(MyListener.class)
   public class Customer {
    }
```

I hope this helps.

-Alex

Comment: Thx Alex. Your answer can help me to implement trigger like action inside one table.
But I need to have this done across tables.

Comment: Ok, maybe I dont understand.  I mean you can make one listener class and pass it to ALL entities, them do generic logic or do if( instanceof .. for specific logic, right ?

Answer (score 0):

I found some links on google, which talks about [Spring managed event listeners with JPA](http://deepintojee.wordpress.com/2012/02/05/spring-managed-event-listeners-with-jpa/)